# Display the terms of a sequence as they are computed

Tags: user-interface, haskell

I wrote a little program that displays, in a window, the first 30 terms of the Fibonacci sequence. However, it does not work. My program (see below) computes all the terms, but only the last term is displayed. I would like to display all 30 terms, as soon as they are computed. What should I do?

```
module Main where

import           Control.Monad         (forM)
import           Graphics.UI.Gtk
import           Graphics.UI.Gtk.Glade

fib :: Int -> Integer
fib 1 = 1
fib 2 = 1
fib n = fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)

data GUI = GUI {
  mainWin :: Window,
  clickMe :: Button,
  display :: Label
  }

loadGlade :: IO GUI
loadGlade = do
  Just xml <- xmlNew "gladeFile.glade"
  mw <- xmlGetWidget xml castToWindow "wdwFirst"
  bc <- xmlGetWidget xml castToButton "btnClick"
  ld <- xmlGetWidget xml castToLabel "lblDisplay"

  return $ GUI mw bc ld

connectGui :: GUI -> IO  (ConnectId Button)
connectGui gui = do
  onDestroy (mainWin gui) mainQuit
  onClicked (clickMe gui) (guiAnswer gui)

guiAnswer :: GUI -> IO()
guiAnswer gui = do
  a<-forM [1..30] (\t -> labelSetText (display gui) (show $ fib t))
  --labelSetText (display gui) "WELCOME!!"
  putStr ""


main :: IO ()
main = do
  initGUI
  gui <- loadGlade
  connectGui gui
  widgetShowAll (mainWin gui)
  mainGUI
```

EDIT:

for postGuiAsync, I tried this:

```
guiAnswer :: GUI -> IO()
guiAnswer gui = do
  a<-forM [1..40] (\t -> postGUIAsync $ labelSetText (display gui) (show $ fib t))
  --labelSetText (display gui) "WELCOME!!"
  --mainContextIteration mainContextDefault False
  print ""
```

but without success (it still displays only the final number), and I'm not sure about my code.

EDIT2:
I tried this :

```
guiAnswer :: GUI -> IO()
guiAnswer gui = do
  forkIO $ forM_ [1..40] (\t -> postGUIAsync $ labelSetText (display gui) (show $ fib t))
```

but it is not correct.Can you help me?

the error is :

```
Couldn't match type `GHC.Conc.Sync.ThreadId' with `()'
 Expected type: IO ()
   Actual type: IO GHC.Conc.Sync.ThreadId
 In a stmt of a 'do' block:
   forkIO
   $ forM_
       [1 .. 40]
       (\ t -> postGUIAsync $ labelSetText (display gui) (show $ fib t))
 In the expression:
   do { forkIO
        $ forM_
            [1 .. 40]
            (\ t -> postGUIAsync $ labelSetText (display gui) (show $ fib t)) }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you're using but I expect that you're overwriting individual values instead of accumulating a list of values to display. `a<-forM [1..30] (\t -> labelSetText (display gui) (show $ fib t))`

Comment: Yes, the expected behaviour is to display the values as soon as they are computed

Comment: And if you compute them too quickly? Suppose that all computations are finished in 0.1 seconds, how should it be displayed?

Comment: that's why I used the fibonacci suite; compute 30 terms takes a few seconds, and only after these few seconds the label's text is changed. That's why I posted this message : I think the entire suite is computed before is is displayed. But you're right : it's still a little bit quick to be sure.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you would could upload the code with all relevant files (i.e. the `xml` files) somewhere. Then I could test my suggestions easily :-)

Comment: ok, and thanks for your help; gui haskell file : http://pastebin.com/G2siMdSa; glade file : http://pastebin.com/U9n8Hw5m. but you will have to install gtk and glade from cabal

Comment: Hmm, `galde` is obsolete (no 0.13 version) and I cannot build it here. You should use `Graphics.UI.Gtk.Builder` instead.

Answer (score 2):

GTK is single-threaded. So while indeed your code in `guiAnswer` will call `labelSetText` as the things are being displayed, the will not actually make use of that data until `guiAnswer` returns.

Blind guess: Try running `mainContextIteration mainContextDefault False` after `labelSetText`.

Better guess: Run the computation in a different thread. But beware that all gtk interaction has to happen from the main thread, so you will have to go through some trouble to synchronize that.

Many years ago I implemented such a display-as-calculation-happens functionality for a [fractal renderer](http://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/292-FrakView__An_Haskell_Renderer_for_Iterated_Function_Systems), but I’m not sure I’d still advocate that style :-)

Comment: There will be some synchronization trouble, but not much: gtk offers `postGUIAsync` (and `postGUISync`) for more convenient synchronization.

Comment: Great. That should make a straight-forward solution based on the original code, by wrapping `guiAnswer` in a `forkIO` and wrapping the `labelSetText` inside `postGUIAsync`. Anyone care te test and post an answer?

Comment: @loveley, don’t forget to wrap the `guiAnswer` (or just the `forM` line) in `forkIO`.

Comment: sorry I don't understand how to do that. Could you show me? I get some errors concerning the mapM function (it needs forkIO[()] and not forkIO())

Comment: Use `mapM_` instead of `mapM`.

Comment: `forkIO` returns a `ThreadId`, but `guiAnswer` should return a `()`. Either prepend the line with `void $` (from `Data.Functor`), or simply put a `return ()` in the following line.

Comment: Well, I can compile the result but, with postGUIAsync &  forkIO, it still displays the last result only, after 10 s of computing

Comment: Try compiling with `-threaded` and run with `+RTS -N`. Or make the project available somewhere so that I can help less blindly.

Comment: I will try to put it in FPComplete, but I'm not sure of the result, because of the GTK packages. As soon as I have sth I will post here the link; maybe can I send you this link by a private message?

Comment: you will find above the 2 files at pastebin. for FPcomplete, I'm having a look.